# Printing sheets on different printers

Tags: excel, vba, printing

I need to print sheets (X & Y) on two different printers (PrinterX & Printer Y).

```
Dim PrinterX as string
PrinterX=activeworkbook.Worksheets("Printers").Range("B1).value
Activerprinter = PrinterX
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("X").Printout

Dim PrinterY as string
PrinterY = Activeworkbook.Worksheets("Printers").Range("B2).value
Activerprinter = PrinterY
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Y").Printout
```

It prints both on the same first printer PrinterX.

I am trying to print X on PrinterX and Y on PrinterY

`application.activeprinter` gives error.

Comment: the code you uploaded will return errors, the second line should be `PrinterX=activeworkbook.Worksheets("Printers").Range("B1").Value` . Also the same for the line before last, it should be `PrinterY = Activeworkbook.Worksheets("Printers").Range("B2").Value`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your "Printers" worksheet has 2 different printers setup in `Range("B1")` , and `Range("B2")`.

**Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub PrinteronDifferentPrinters()

Dim PrinterX As String
Dim PrinterY As String

PrinterX = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Printers").Range("B1").Value
Activerprinter = PrinterX
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("X").PrintOut

PrinterY = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Printers").Range("B2").Value
Activerprinter = PrinterY
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Y").PrintOut

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

you could use a loop not to repeat same code twice;

```
Sub main()
    Dim iCell As Long

    With Worksheets("Printers").Range("B1:B2") '<--| reference range with printers
        For iCell = 1 To .Count '<--|loop through it
            ActivePrinter = .Cells(iCell, 1).Value '<--| set activeprinter to curent cell value
            Worksheets(Array("X", "Y")(iCell - 1)).PrintOut '<--| define array with corresponding wanted sheets names and printout current one
       Next iCell
    End With
End Sub
```